# Text Scroll On Hover Not work With jQuery 2.2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have This Code for scroll text on hover `div` using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 390px; margin-left: 50px; background-color: #ddd;">
  <div class="tooMuchWrapper"><span class="tooMuchText tooMuchText1">Got too much text to fit in your content area? Just hover for more more more more more more!</span></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tooMuchText1").hoverForMore({
    "speed": 300,
    "loop": false
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.tooMuchText {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: default;
}
```

But In action my code not work. I test with jQuery 2.2.0. how do can I fix this problem?

demo [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wzhpbhcf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you JSFIDDLE, remove the } on line 275...
updated version:

```
$(function()
{
 $(".tooMuchText1").hoverForMore({
   "speed": 300,
   "loop": false,
 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wzhpbhcf/1/

Answer (score 0):

change `$(function()
} {
$(".tooMuchText1").hoverForMore({
  "speed": 300,
  "loop": false,
});
});`

to

`$(function()
{
$(".tooMuchText1").hoverForMore({
  "speed": 300,
  "loop": false,
});
});`